# FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 10 in HTC salsa

Tags: android, opengl-es, coverflow

Hi friends i create one app in this app i use the coverflow for display book images.
i use the opengl coverflow from this side.[get the sources code.](https://github.com/jackfengji/glcoverflow)i use this code in my app and create the coverflow.witch work successfully on all device.and i got the output look like this.[image]

in my device.i use the app in below device.
**Sony Xperia mt27I,
Kindle Fire,
Samsung Gallexy Tab 2.
Micromax Funbook p275,
and HTC Salsa**

my question is above of all device in my coverflow app work successfully.only **HTC Salsa** i got the following Error.

```
02-14 19:14:02.522: E/AndroidRuntime(15302): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 10
02-14 19:14:02.522: E/AndroidRuntime(15302): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No config chosen
02-14 19:14:02.522: E/AndroidRuntime(15302):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:774)
02-14 19:14:02.522: E/AndroidRuntime(15302):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:919)
02-14 19:14:02.522: E/AndroidRuntime(15302):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1264)
02-14 19:14:02.522: E/AndroidRuntime(15302):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1118).
```

i don't know what is the problem.if about app version i check this issue.but no problem about app version.

please any have any idea then give me answer.
Thanks.